# Video ontimeupdate highlights specific line per second

Tags: javascript, html

My script is set up so there is a log of text on the left and a video on the right. The log has a time stamp on each line and the video playback position (eg. 40 seconds) corresponds to the correct time stamp so the text and video are in sync.

Currently, the page scrolls with the video playback, and this is done by anchors (the playback position of the video corresponds to the anchor id of each line of text).

What I'm trying to do now is dynamically highlight a line of text that matches the video position. I can put a replace line within my ontimeupdate function but this will highlight a line and when it highlights the next line, it won't remove the previous one, so you'll end up with the entire page having been highlighted. I'm trying to have it highlight 1 line that is matched at a time and then remove the highlighting and move to the next line.

Within the ontimeupdate function is there a way of putting in code that only actions until the next ontimeupdate?

I guess the question doesn't really need my code and it's more conceptual as I'm pretty new to Javascript and I'm not familiar with the various functions within just yet. But if seeing some part of the code would be helpful to providing a solution, let me know and I'll update the post!

EDIT: an insight into the way I was thinking of doing this so far. Within the ontimeupdate I could have an if statement like this:

if ontimeupdate playback position matches line in string, highlight line

else if ontimeupdate playback position does not match line then if line has highlight code then remove

Comment: assume you have css `.highlight{}`. Use `document.querySelector(".highlight").classList.remove("highlight)` then highlight the current line

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [WebVTT API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API)? I'm not entirely sure of what you are really after, but it seems this could help a bit, avoiding you to have to do all the syncing code. Plus, it offers [some events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrackCue#Event_handlers) that you could hook to.

Comment: @Kaiido I may be wrong but from what I read of WebVTT before it's more like a subtitling, so it overlays it on the video. Mine is having the log to one side and the video to the other and the user can scroll through and the left side will scroll to the corresponding line. The logic for syncing is complete, so the hard bit is done, the question is more about highlighting the line in question and then when it moves to the next line it removes the previous highlighting - thanks for your help though!

Comment: @NamTang what would the logic be to remove highlighting apart from the line that matches the current time stamp? would it be an if statement like I put in my original post's edit

Comment: i have done this recently, what i do is `track.addEventListener("cuechange")` on the `showing` track to remove `.highlight` from current `highlighted` then hightlight by `track.activeCues[0].id` or `track.activeCues[0].startTime`